# Display the unicode 32 symbols in R

Tags: r, unicode

How to display the Unicode 32 symbols with code over \uFFFF wherever we can do that in R, for example, with print(...)?
For example, I try to print, the symbol \u1F946 as print("\uD83E\uDD46") but as the result I have got the rectangular symbol.

Comment: The Unicode symbols have to be supported by the font file your console is using to render them. A rectangle typically means the font being used in your console does not include information on how to draw that symbol.

Comment: @AllanCameron, so how to solve it?

Comment: It's not really anything to do with R. R will happily display the characters if your font supports them. If you are using RStudio, you can select the font that is used in your console. Find a font that supports the symbols you want to see, install it, and use that as your console font. As far as I know, GNU unifont has the largest unifont code coverage of the monospaced fonts suitable for a console. Try installing that.

Comment: https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/1F946-rifle … Try `unifont_upper-15.0.01.ttf`, _Unifont Upper_ font